# iPhone (iOS) download an MP4 from a link on a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, mp4

I've tried the HTML5 download tag, JavaScript, JQuery, and a few other tricks here and there, none will download the file to the Album.  Photos you can long click and get "Save Image".  Even from the Actions page, there Message, Email, share on Facebook and Twitter, etc. but no save.  Is there any way to allow a user, without downloading another app or jailbreaking, to allow a video download from a website?   We need something user friendly.   We have a site that generates a custom video and we want users to be able to save it to their device.  I've been unable through Google or searching here to find a method that works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can download video files directly to an iOS device without using a specific app (i.e. A YouTube downloader)

This is an iOS restriction.